# Are 变 and 変 the same?

Tags: kanji, orthography, chinese, kyūjitai-and-shinjitai

Is there a difference between 变 and 変 or are they different versions of the same thing i.e. traditional/simplified?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They are both slightly different simplifications of the traditional Chinese character which is 變.

变 is the simplified Chinese and 変 the *shinjitai*, i.e. the Japanese simplification.

Often the simplifications are the same, but it also often happens that traditional Chinese characters have slightly different simplifications in Chinese and Japanese, for example

> simplified Chinese ← traditional Chinese → simplified Japanese
>
> - 亚 ← 亞 → 亜
> - 压 ← 壓 → 圧
> - 围 ← 圍 → 囲
> - 驿 ← 驛 → 駅
> - etc.

Also sometimes Simplified Chinese has a simplification where Japanese has none (e.g. 东 ← 東) and sometimes Japanese has a simplification where Simplified Chinese has none (e.g. 壹 → 壱).

Moreover, it may happen that certain characters are treated as being the "same", but their renderings in Japanese and Chinese are slightly different, e.g.

> simplified Chinese ← traditional Chinese ～ "traditional Japanese" → simplified Japanese
>
> - 缘 ← {{zh-CN:緣}} ～ {{ja:緣}} → 縁

where "traditional Japanese" is just a nickname for 旧字体 *ky­ūjitai*. (By the way, displaying different regional variants of the same character can be achieved using language codes as described [here on meta](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1502/1628).)

You can usually look this up in any 漢和辞典, but a quick way to check this would be on the Wiktionary page, for example for the character in question it would be [https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/变](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8F%98).

Comment: So cool that you put Chinese versions at the "west" side and Japanese ones at the "east" side! :-)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinjitai#Differences_in_simplification_between_Chinese_and_Japanese ; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differences_between_Shinjitai_and_Simplified_characters